# best data structure to dynamically hold and display markers on a map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, visualization

We have markers as in google maps of location attractions. What would be a good data structure to hold these markers as I need to grab the ones relevant for a user's screen. They will be able to see X amount of locations and I need to grab the most relevant markers to display as quickly as possible. Ideally I can access attributes about each "marker" to make a heuristic to choose the best ones possible.

Also is there a good rule of thumb for how many markers should be displayed at any one time on a user's screen?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend R-tree or Quadtree. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree